# Retrieve a text node with Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I'm quite new to *Simple HTML DOM Parser*. I want to get a child element from the following HTML:

```
<div class="article">
 <div style="text-align:justify">
    <img src="image.jpg" title="image">
    <br>
    <br>
    "Text to grab"
    <div>......</div>
    <br></br>
    ................
    ................
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the text **"Text to grab"**

So far I've tried the following query:

```
$html->find('div[class=article] div')->children(3);
```

But it's not working. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: it would help to have some context for your code, not just one line...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Which **child** do you want to get text from ?

Comment: Unfortunately `Simple HTML DOM Parser` doesnt consider text as a node, so that wont work... You can try using `find('text')` but be aware that you'll have empty rows beacause of the `<br>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always in the same place you can do:

```
$html->find('.article text', 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `simple_html_dom` here. It can be done with [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Both are part of the PHP core.

Example:

```
// your sample data
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="article">
 <div style="text-align:justify">
    <img src="image.jpg" title="image">
    <br>
    <br>
    "Text to grab"
    <div>......</div>
    <br></br>
    ................
    ................
  </div>
</div>
EOF;

// create a document from the above snippet
// if you are loading from a remote url use:
//   $doc->load($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// initialize a XPath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// get the text node (also text elements in xml/html are nodes
$query = '//div[@class="article"]/div/br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]';
$textToGrab = $selector->query($query)->item(0);

// remove newlines on start and end using trim() and output the text
echo trim($textToGrab->nodeValue);
```

Output:

```
"Text to grab"
```

Comment: `You don't need simple_html_dom here` I'm curious why and where it should be used ? =)

Comment: @Enissay `simple_html_dom` was developed in times of PHP4. PHP4 had no builtin XPath support.

Comment: I see, this answers a question I was asking myself for a long time... So "new" the built-in php dom can completely replace it ? If so, I'm curious why It still widely used :/

Comment: I'm not using it :) And also I would not encourage anybody to use it in a new project. While it was a great library in former times, the new builtin XPath class is much faster. I guess it was such a great project that there is still so much documentation out there, so that noobies might think it is still the preferred solution.

Comment: haha, I'm one of these noobies xD ... thanks a lot for these answers <3

Comment: Well, there's also the idea that most php programmers are more comfortable with css than xpath. I think it actually makes sense to use simple in many situations.